# Выбрать порт для модема

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть

Пытаюсь воспользоваться программой `Gnome PPP`, чтобы настроить соединение через мой модем. Проблема в том, что нужно выбрать порт своего модема, а его нет в списке и по умолчанию не определился. Настоящий порт вы видите в окне `Modem Manager GUI`, то есть `ttyACM0`, но такого порта нет в настройках `GPPP`. Я слышал что нужно что-то куда-то переместить, но не понял что к чему.

Модель модема: `UML 290`

Comment: Вы хотите подключить модем к интернету?

Comment: в последнее время довольно популярными стали модемы, которые сразу предоставляют сетевой интерфейс (в рамках протокола usb). у вас, случайно, не такой модем?

Comment: @drfels укажите модель модема (что написано на нем самом и искать в выводе команды **lspci**)

Answer (score 1):

Команда `ln` делает ссылку. Имеет форму `ln <На что ссылаемся> <Файл-ссылка>` или как-то так. Мне помогла команда `ln -s /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/modem`.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать символическую ссылку, например с /dev/ttyACM0 на /dev/ttyS0

Comment: Как её сделать?

Comment: `ln -s /dev/ttyACM0 /dev/modem` — пытаюсь опять в gnome ppp, выбираю в списке устройств /dev/modem и получаю: 
`--> Cannot open /dev/modem: Permission denied
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: Permission denied
--> Cannot open /dev/modem: Permission denied`

Comment: @drfels добавьте своего пользователя в групу /modem

Comment: Извините за такой банальный вопрос: но как?

Comment: @drfels вот так http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B#%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_gui